# How to re-direct Internet https requests to an intranet https server without untrusted server issue

Tags: networking, ssl, nginx, https, redirect

*Scenario*: We have a device (R) the broadcasts a wifi network. The objective is to be able to restrict client devices connected to this wifi to content only served by R. R has a nginx server that serves content and a node service to render some captive portal functionality.

*Challenge*: Although we expect devices connected to the Wifi to only be served content from R there is no reason why a user won't key in an Internet hostname (like https://google.com/) is his browser's address field. For such Internet **http** URLs we redirect request to R's https service using 301 and we don't face any issues however for Internet **https** URLs on the Internet we get an **untrusted** https certificate popup in the client browser which I would like to do away with.

*Sought Solution:* I would like **https** requests to also be seamlessly served by R without client devices complaining about https certificates. Is this doable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTPS is HTTP inside an SSL/TLS tunnel. To establish this tunnel you need a proper identification of the peer, otherwise man-in-the-middle attacks would be possible. Since the redirection is done by HTTP you first need to establish the SSL/TLS tunnel and then you can redirect. This means, that if you are trying to redirect google.com you would need a certificate which identifies yourself as google.com and this certificate needs to be signed by somebody trusted by the browser (i.e. a trusted root CA). Since you don't have this and probably never will get (because only the owner of the domain should get such certificate) what you are trying to do is not possible.

Comment: If you control all the clients on the network you could create your own CA root certificate and install that on all the clients. With this you could create certificates for the requested domains on-the-fly and and serve content. Also you would have to deactivate pinned certificates.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, because it violates how things are supposed to work. Consider this: If an attacker could do the same thing, they could redirect banking websites that use https to a server that they control, either by being on the same network or via malware. The nature of https prevents this from happening.